# sit, set, or put him among my classmates

Tags: word-choice, verbs, sit-set

> I set him among my friends
>   I put him among my friends
>   I sit him among my friends

Having take into account [previous explanations](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38084/sit-or-set-yourself-at-the-table), I assume that the third one is used a more polite and bossy construction. Other than that, the former two are used as more colloquial. Is this accurate?

Comment: Please explain in the question what have you meant to say by these sentences: that you believe him to be one of your friends, that you have added him to the list of your friends, or that you have made him sit among your friends in the classrom.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, unless OP is *literally* talking about a *physical location*, more likely phrasing is...

> *I **count** him among* (or *[as] one of*) *my friends*

Note that whereas *put, sit* would only normally be used in the "location" sense, *set* probably wouldn't be used at all today (it's a dated usage, bordering on archaic except where the referent is inanimate and the sense is *arrange, organise, display* rather than *locate, position*).

Answer (score 0):

> I **set** him among my friends.

I would not use *set* with people, only things.

> I **set** the glasses next to the plates.

Next:

> I **put** him among my friends.

This might be OK but more context is needed.

Finally:

> I **sit** him among my friends.

This is close, but is a rough form, because you do not physically "sit" people.
It would be better to say:

> I **had** him **sit** among my friends.

or more polite:

> > I **asked** him **to sit** among my friends.

Comment: *Set* could be appropriate, for example, if referring to ranking or classification, although I too would refrain from using it to refer to physical placement.

Comment: I might also say "I seated him among my friends." if I were selecting where he sat, similar to how I would say "The host seated us at a table by the window."

Comment: "set" can be used with animals: "That will set the fox among the chickens!" is a reasonably common metaphor, no?

Comment: @A.Beth I am a city kid so I don't really understand what the phrase implies. Is it like [***set***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/set) sense 4 "to put in the proper or designated place   ⇒ "to set a wheel on an axle""?

Comment: @user3169 : No, it's more of an eliding of "set loose" -- another term would be "loose the fox among the chickens," a metaphor for "now there will be running around and screaming because of this fact/person." But there's also, "Set the hounds on him," which would mean "give the hounds the signal to attack." (Which "set the fox among the chickens" also somewhat partakes of, as a metaphor, if more in a permissive sense than an imperative one.) Thus, "I set him among my friends" is odd, but not an impossible construction to me.

Comment: @A.Beth That seems to be this definition [***set loose***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/set-loose); a bit different than *set* by itself.